# SQL SSRS current month from month value match

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have some data;

customer name    product    month   year

In my dataset the only filter I have is for current year = true

Otherwise, I have the rest of the fields above. When I run my report, it is printing each month's totals. I only want it to print the current month's totals. I've seem some other posts here and tried to mimick / copy but no luck

So it's printing  Customer   Stickers   Jan Feb Mar   2013, when I really only want it to print the current month, Mar

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

MonthName(Month(Fields!CurrentDate.Value),False)   try this

If you let me know the exact field you are using i can help you with the expression

Comment: Fields!Month.Value is the name of the field, I tried what you posted but it still wants to display 3 columns (1 for each month), with an #error in the header)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add another filter to get just the current month:

SQL Syntax for current monnth:

```
select Dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

OR

```
where thing = Dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just filter out data for current month in the query of your dataset?
Something like:

```
WHERE [year] = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND [month] = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```